# How to run javascript code on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, squarespace

I'm creating a squarespace website in which I have a navigation bar.

I would like to add a javascript code as a link in the navigation bar.

The javascript code is the following:

```
<div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script> 
</div>
```

I have the following html code: (I got it with FireBug)

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="cf">
        <li class=" active-link">
            <a href="/">page1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page2/">page2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I cannot edit the code above but I'm able to inject header code.

So, how can I add the javascript code as a third link in the navigation bar?

Thanks a lot!

**edit**

So I've added the following code

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 $('nav ul').append('<li><a onClick="test()" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a></li>');
}
</script>
```

but I need the original javascript code within the append. I need the actual code to be the link. How do I do that? If you see the javascript in Firefox you'll understand what I mean. I need the actual link it generates in the navigation bar.

Thanks!

Comment: i would start by clarifying that it is javascript you're asking about here...

Comment: If you mean how to add a link to navigation then `$('nav ul').append('<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>');`.

Comment: @mdesdev thanks but I'm not getting it to work

Comment: someone had suggested <nav id="new" onClick="test()">; it's almost there, the thing is this code calls the function "test" after the click on ANY link. how do I reference only one link? that is, only one href?

Comment: @user3507859 Did you include jQuery library? Did you put jQuery code between `<script> </script>` tags and wrapped in document ready function?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
 $('nav ul').append('<li><a onClick="yourFunction()" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a></li>');
}
```

Since you specify you don't have direct access to the html. Only the header.

This will add your menu item with a link, that upon click, executes the function `yourFunction()`. It will add this item as soon as the page loads.

Note: You need jQuery for the above. But it is also possible with raw Js.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It works if the fuction called is a simple alert message. I'm not getting the original javascript code into a function, can you please help me out with that? I'm trying to include the <script> </script> tags but I doesn't work.
Another thing is that although this is a great solution, it doesn't add the java as a link. If you are able to see what the code actually is, it says "Sacola de compras (0)" (which means "cart bag" and shows how many items you are buying in the shop. Is there a way to show the actual javascript as the link?